# How do I check to see if user has PIN code enabled on an iOS Device

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch

If there a way to see if a user has enabled a PIN on a device using Objective-C?  I need to apply different security rules for people without a PIN enabled.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not there yet, but I'm hopeful for such an API in iOS soon, because it likely already exists in private form— Apple's "Find My Friends" application actually does exactly what you're looking to do: if you have a device passcode set, it will skip the authentication step.

Comment: Yes, with exchange based mail, you can also specify that a pin code is required to send/receive mail.

Answer (score 0):

No. I've never seen this in the SDK.